# SproutCore Todo List Error

Tags: javascript, sproutcore

Going through the SproutCore ["Getting started"](http://sproutcore.com/guides/getting_started.html) tutorial and have a problem.

Inside the Todos.todoListController there is a function:

```
Todos.todoListController = SC.ArrayController.create({

  // ...

  remaining: function() {
    return this.filterProperty('isDone', false).get('Length');
  }.property('@each.isDone')
});
```

For some reason, this will not show the actual number of remaining items.  It displays as 'undefined':

[image]

I wrote the code myself on the first go around, but copied the code from the tutorial and tried it for trouble shooting - still gets the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...

Just saw they host the code on GitHub and there the code works.

turns out the `.get('Length')` has to be a lowercase 'l'

so... `.get('length')` is the solution.